# What is the current state of the art solution for Movielens 100k / 20M?

Tags: recommender-system, movielens

I found [Basic recommendation system for Movilens dataset using Keras](https://github.com/CVxTz/Recommender_keras) which has a solution which works ok (MAE 0.84).

What is the current state of the art for this dataset?